# Assigning movements to counters for a board game, using die rolls.

Tags: python

I have finished writing a program, and was wondering if I could make it any more efficient or generally more sophisticated that the current version.
The below section of code is where I think improvement could be made...any suggestions?

EDIT: The below functions focus on the die roll result of '6' which allows the player to move to the next avaliable space on the board. Note, it's mainly about making the below code better and more efficient than the actual function of the program.

```
def sixcheck(player1, player2):
    piece = [[True,1],[True,1]]
    occupied = [player1[1], player2[0], player2[1]]
    while player1[0] + piece[0][1] in occupied:
       piece[0][1] += 1
    if player1[0] + piece[0][1] > 11:
       piece[0][0] = False
    occupied = [player1[0], player2[0], player2[1]]
    while player1[1] + piece[1][1] in occupied:
       piece[1][1] += 1
    if player1[1] + piece[1][1] > 11:
       piece[1][0] = False    
    return piece

def counter(piece):
    if piece[0][0] == True and piece[1][0] == True:
        print("")
        choice = input("->")
        while choice != "1" and choice != "2":
            print("")
            choice = input("->")
    elif piece[0][0] == True:
        choice = "1"
        input("")
    elif piece[1][0] == True:
        choice = "2"
        input("")
    return choice
```

## Section of a larger function (the rest is non-important)

```
while not p_winner:
    if p1_turn:
        print(players[0][2],"(#) It's your move")
        player1 = players[0]
        player2 = players[1]
        move_pieces(player1,player2)
        players[0] = player1
        players[1] = player2
        p1_turn = False
    elif p1_turn == False:
        print(players[1][2],"(=) It's your move")
        player1 = players[1]
        player2 = players[0]
        move_pieces(player1,player2)
        players[1] = player1
        players[0] = player2
        p1_turn = True
    game_board(players)
```

Any help to making the above more 'professional' would be much appreciated ^^

Comment: The title should not contain the question; questions are for the body. The title of your post should be the function/purpose of your code.

Comment: What does this program do? If we know what your program is trying to do, we can provide better reviews.

Comment: Based on the drastic edits in the revision history and the lack of background information about what the code is supposed to accomplish, I've closed this question as Unclear What You Are Asking. If you still need advice, please ask a new question that addresses the complaints in these comments.

Answer (score 7):

#### Tedious `if` conditions

You can shorten all the `if something == True:` to simply `if something:`,
for example this:

> ```
> if piece[0][0] == True and piece[1][0] == True:
>     print("Which piece will you move: 1 or 2?")
> ```

to this:

```
if piece[0][0] and piece[1][0]:
    print("Which piece will you move: 1 or 2?")
```

---

You can shorten this too:

> ```
> if True_move == v:
>     return True
> else:
>     return False
> ```

to simply:

```
return True_move == v
```

#### Pythonic coding style

The naming convention for function names is `snake_case`,
so `Valid_Move` should have been `valid_move`.
Actually `is_valid_move` would be even better.

See [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), the official Python coding style guide.

See also [PEP20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), the Zen of Python.

#### Magic numbers

Number 11 appears to be magic. 
It would be good to put it in a variable with a descriptive name.

Comment: Are there any other things I could improve?

Comment: Hi @PontiusPilateVII, you accepted early. Probably there are other things to improve, I just don't have time now to get deeper into your code to understand it properly. I think you should un-accept and wait for more reviews.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to echo the comments: it would be really helpful if you told us what this code is supposed to do, exactly, and maybe explained some of the pieces that touch on what you have here, like what type `players`  is and why you chose to represent it that way.

In your second code snippet, you have this section:

```
 player1 = players[0]
 player2 = players[1]
 move_pieces(player1,player2)
 players[0] = player1
 players[1] = player2
```

which is duplicated in the second arm of your `if` statement, but with player 1 and player 2 reversed. I would change your `move_pieces` function to return a list or tuple of the new player states, instead of modifying them by side effect and then reassigning them into the list. Something like:

```
def move_pieces(p1, p2):
    # Do what you need to do
    return (p1, p2)
```

Then get the return values and assign them into the `players` list:

```
player1, player2 = move_pieces(players[0], players[1])
players[0] = player1
players[1] = player2
```

This replaces the original piece of code with:

```
if p1_turn:
   players[0], players[1] = move_pieces(players[0], players[1])
   p1_turn = False
else:
   players[1], players[0] = move_pieces(players[1], players[0])
   p1_turn = True
```

I feel there are other places this code could be tightened up, but without knowing what it's supposed to do, I don't want to suggest anything that misses the point.